# "Headers Already Sent" Nightmare on Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I have read all posts everywhere, I have tried everything, even If I save the plugin with nothing but the "Plugin Name: " it still says Headers are already sent. Error shows it's on line 1 in which I only have `<?php` with no spaces, I have already tried saving with different code editors, its utf8. In fact plugin was working and suddenly error started appearing for no apparent reason.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Control_De_Arrendamiento
 * @version 0.1
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Control de Arrendamiento
Plugin URI: 
Description: Control de Arrendamiento
Author: 
Version: 0.1
Author URI: 
*/
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the plugin when it’s iust the name? Is it in a comment?

Comment: make sure your editor do not save it with a BOM

Comment: turn off debug display but turn on the log and check errors

Comment: Today it just started working with no changes at all, now I can't even recreate the problem. @MarkKaplun already had checked for BOM but wasn't used on the file.

Comment: Code added @JacobPeattie